# How to get lastest chapter URL visited of each book in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i have a book site built with laravel, is there any way to know and store lastest chapter URL visited of each book on database? For help next times, when user come a book, he will know where he can countinue reading.
Thanks!

Comment: You can store the last visited URL or some page or book information in DB.

Comment: You can use cookies for that, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using cookies will allow the user to pick up where they left off, even if they are not logged in, but you should set it on the user account as well, that way you can track user progress even if they sign in on a different device. It helps if users have to log in to read your book, because then you'll always have an authenticated user you can register the log to.

I would suggest you track user ID, chapter ID and perhaps book ID, plus a datetime (can be a created_at column that is populated automatically). By logging these things you can tell a lot more about book usage and user behavior than if you just log what URL they visited last.

You can listen for the `retreived` event and then create the log item:

```
<?php

class Chapter extends Model
{
    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'retreived' => LogUserReading::class,
    ];
}

class LogUserReading
{
    public function handle(Chapter $chapter)
    {
        ReadingLog::create(Auth::user()->id, $chapter->id, $chapter->book->id);
    }
}
```

Then to find out for instance where a user last left off, just fetch the latest item from the reading log.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Redis - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redis

```
 Redis::set('latestChapter', '35');
```

Comment: But my site CMS is a product of other author. Can i still customize source code and install package by myself without author? and what is '35' meaning? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't quite get your question. Laravel Redis is an open source technology that means its a free to use technology, licence under MIT. 35 is just a sample chapter.